# Python Jupyter Notebook - Summary Display only showing last result

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two datasets and I try to see summary of these two datasets at same time via 2 different commands. However, Jupyter is displaying only last result. Is there way I can see both in next cell?

```
    raw_data = {'age1': [23,45,21],'age2': [10,20,50], 'age3':[44,55,77]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2','age3'])

    raw_data = {'age1': [23,45,21],'age2': [10,20,50], 'age3':[44,55,77]}
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['age1','age2','age3'])

    np.sum(df['age1'])
    np.sum(df['age2'])
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup at the beginning of the notebook to show all intermediate results from a single cell:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Answer (score -1):

Jupyter only automatically prints out the last command of a cell. You could either use print() around each of the objects you want to output, put both commands on the same line separated by commas or move one of them to the next cell. The output will differ slightly for each case so use the one that gives you the result you want.